# Why do they say PBN is under RNAV?

Tags: navigation, rnav, rnp

**PBN exists under the umbrella of area navigation (RNAV).**
[FAA AIM, Section 2. Performance-Based Navigation (PBN) and Area Navigation (RNAV)]

As far as I know, RNAV and RNP exist under PBN, and as an abbreviation of Performance based navigation, I know that they belong to a large category. However, FAA AIM states that PBN is under the umbrella of RNAV. Any detailed reasons?

Comment: @DeltaLima, Why did you delete the answer as rude or spam?  It wasn't correct in my opinion, but definitely not rude.

Comment: @MichaelHall: Because it linked to the registration page a government program, so spam.

Comment: @mins, I cannot see what you are talking any more about to verify, but it asks a question about the FAA, a *government agency/program*, so a link to an FAA page (if that's what it was) isn't spam by the definition of the term.

Comment: @MichaelHall: No that was the government of Pakistan and not related to aviation at all. The link was hidden behind "*Need More detail check here*", obviously intentional.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Nevermind then...  Thanks.